# Best way to change block´s template?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, certification

I've been studing for the **Magento certification** and I came across a question in the **swiftotter** practice exam that said:

[image]

Can someone explain me **why the answer I chose is incorrect**? I thought the way you **changed a block´s layout** was with the answer I selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Doesn't work
2. It works and the Best one,

   > higher priority than the `<argument name="template" xsi:type...`, explanation in 3.
3. Works too :

   > It works but the second one is the best because when the template
   >   value is specified in the template attribute `template="..."` have a
   >   higher priority when Magento generate layouts than  when the
   >   template is set in `<argument name="...">` one
4. Doesn't work :

   > (`action` node is deprecated)

---

#### Magento DevDocs Says :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### It's not the prefered way

the preferred way is the answer marked in green.

you can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html).